# List of heterogenenous array

Tags: java, android, arrays, gps, location

I am a "Java noob", so be patient with me :)

I need to create a particular structure that contains heterogeneous fields.

I'm getting the `Android.Location` from a GPS device (my smartphone) and I want to store all the Locations, but I need to add to each of them some other fields. So, my structure will be something like that:

```
[0]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
[1]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
[2]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
[3]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
[4]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
...
[n]: Location - String - int - String - int - String - String
```

I don't know the number of "rows" because it depends on some variables (like time, route, etc).

Which is the best way to make it in Java?

**UPDATE**

Is it correct this solution?

```
public Class LocationPlus {
    private Location location;
    private String string1;
    private int int1;
    private String string2;
    private int int2;

    // Constructor, setters, getters
}
```

Then, in my main:

```
List<LocationPlus> locationPlus = new ArrayList<LocationPlus>();
locationPlus.add(new LocationPlus(location, “marco”, 1, “bianco”, 2));
locationPlus.add(new LocationPlus(location, “luca”, 3, “arancio”, 4));
locationPlus.add(new LocationPlus(location, “giovanni”, 5, “rossi”, 6));
```

Comment: you have to make a list of custom object in which object contains all the data you need.

Comment: Can you write a "code sample" for me pls?

Comment: ok for clarification you need Location , some int , and some strings in it right ?

Comment: Yep, I do. I thought to create a new class "LocationPlus" which has Location, string, string, int, int as fields, then I will create an ArrayList of LocationPlus. What do you think?

Comment: yes i said same i have made sample do you need it ?

Comment: Zircon made it for you i have made as it is you can use that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think your best option is to create a class which holds all of these fields (including the `Location`) and then use a suitable `Collection` for them such as an `ArrayList`.

```
List<LocationData> locations = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then use getter/setter pairs in your custom `LocationData` class to get each field that you've been wanting to store.

The custom class, as an example:

```
public class LocationData {
     //Name these appropriately! I don't know what they're for.
     private Location location;
     private String string1;
     private int num1;
     private String string2;
     private int num2;
     private String string3;
     private String string4;

     //Constructor
     public LocationData(Location loc, String s1, int n1, String s2, int n2, String s3, String s4) {
         location = loc;
         //And so on for each field
         ...
     }

     //One pair of methods for each field
     public Location getLocation() {
         return location;
     }
     public void setLocation(Location loc) {
         location = loc;
     }
```

Comment: What makes you think OP requires setters? From the description, I think the class should be immutable. Getters yes, but I see no reason for setters.

Comment: I updated my question while you wrote your answer. They seems same solution :) Is it correct my use in my main method?

Comment: @Ray I'm just used to making Java beans for most everything. If there's no need to alter the data then, yes, setters are not needed.
Domenico, You can use the object and lists wherever they are needed, including the main method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `ArrayList`. This is basically an array, (which you can use to store the information) but the number of elements isn't set. This means that you don't need to know the number of "rows". You could create an `ArrayList` with the type as another Array. This array could be the type of `Object` to store the different types of variables.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> information = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
// The Object[] within the '<>' is the type of the ArrayList
// In this case, the type of the ArrayList happens to be another
// array. This array has a type of Object, meaning almost
// anything can be stored in it.

public void updateInformation(Location loc, String str1, int num1, String str2, int num2, String str3, String str4) {

  int currentSize = 0; // The current size of the ArrayList

  currentSize = information.size(); // Returns the size of the ArrayList

  // Create a new Object array with a size of seven since
  // you have seven pieces of information to store.
  information.add(new Object[7]);

  // For the following, get the newly created Object array,
  // and store your information within the Object array's seven
  // indexes.

  information.get(currentSize)[0] = loc; // Index 0 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[1] = loc; // Index 1 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[2] = loc; // Index 2 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[3] = loc; // Index 3 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[4] = loc; // Index 4 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[5] = loc; // Index 5 of Object Array
  information.get(currentSize)[6] = loc; // Index 6 of Object Array
  // Only go to index six. This is because array SIZES start at 1, but
  // array INDEXES start at 0. This means the max index of an array will
  // always be one less than the size.

}

// The index referring to the index of the ArrayList of the set of
// desired information.
public Object[] getInformation(int index) {

  return information.get(index);
  //  Return the object array with the information

}
```

Comment: I preferred the Zircon solution, but thank you anyway :)